# How to insert new line in the error messages and also how to insert only one error message per validation instead of 3

Tags: java, hibernate

How do I insert a new line in Hibernate Error messages

I am getting the following output

School Name : [Textbox]  School Name can't be Empty
Must be Alphabets                                           [Submit button (Around 5 tab spaces approx)]
Only 255 characters are allowed.

```
@NotEmpty(message="\n School Name can't be empty")
@Pattern(regexp= "[a-zA-Z-\\s]+",message="Must be alphabets")
@Size(min = 1 , max = 255 ,message="Only 255 characters are allowed")
```

Comment: Where are you trying to output your message?

Comment: I am trying to output my error message below text box.

Comment: I believe you have html page. There \n is ignored by design. Convert it to <br/>